# Using a generating function for deducing the asymptotic growth of a sequence - Wikipedia example

Tags: asymptotics, generating-functions

The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) on generating functions contains the following assertion, but offers no details about how to derive it:

> If an ordinary generating function $G(a_n; x)$ that has a finite radius of convergence of $r$ can be written as
> $$
> G(a_n; x) = \frac{A(x) + B(x) \left (1- \frac{x}{r} \right )^{-\beta}}{x^{\alpha}}
> $$
> where each of $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ is a function that is analytic to a radius of convergence greater than $r$ (or is entire), and where $B(r) \neq 0$ then
> $$ 
> {\displaystyle a_{n}\sim {\frac {B(r)}{r^{\alpha }\Gamma (\beta )}}\,n^{\beta -1}(1/r)^{n}\sim {\frac {B(r)}{r^{\alpha }}}{\binom {n+\beta -1}{n}}(1/r)^{n}={\frac {B(r)}{r^{\alpha }}}\left(\!\!{\binom {\beta }{n}}\!\!\right)(1/r)^{n}}
> $$

How is this derived?

Comment: A standard reference text for this kind of claim is [Flajolet and Sedgwick](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html).

Comment: See also https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10#iv It is a special case of Darboux’s method.